# unwanted whited space while appending element using class in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Below code creates unwanted space before value1 and value2 while appending element using .append() of jquery and based on class

I am trying to add indicator on every table and tried different options of .before() , append() but prepend is close but white space is causing issue

```js
$(".step").prepend('<span class="stepPos">1</span>')
```

```css
table, tr, td, th{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:0px !important;
}

.stepPos{
 position:relative;
 left:-15px;
}


body{
  padding:20px
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th >heading</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="step">value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table>
<tr>
  <th >heading2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="step">value2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: before value1 and value2. sorry I am updating the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `position: relative` and a negative offset, the space for the element (in its original position) is still reserved within its parent container, all you're doing is moving the element relative to that space (which can be a bit surprising). The space before "value" and "value2" is where the `1` would be if you hadn't moved it with `left: -15px`.

This should help visualize that:

```css
.x {
  background: #ccc;
}
.offset {
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.spacer {
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="x">x</span>
  <span>y</span>
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="container">
  <span class="x offset">x</span>
  <span>y</span>
</div>
```

You can see how the space for the `x` is still reserved in its original location; when we offset where the `x` is, we just offset it relative to that reserved space, without changing where that reserved space is.

To avoid having that space taken up by the `stepPos` elements, make them `position: absolute` instead. To make sure they're positioned relative to their parent `td`, you'll also need to add `position: relative` to the `td`s so they're offset parents for their content.

```
td.step {
  position: relative;
}

.stepPos{
  position:absolute;
  left:-15px;
}
```

Example:

```js
$(".step").prepend('<span class="stepPos">1</span>');
```

```css
table, tr, td, th{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:0px !important;
}

td.step {
  position: relative;
}

.stepPos{
  position:absolute;
  left:-15px;
}

body{
  padding:20px
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th >heading</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="step">value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table>
<tr>
  <th >heading2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="step">value2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Two corrections made
1. For setting padding 0, you need to set style to "table{}" need not to "table, tr,td ..."
2. As styles are interpreted top to bottom, placed the table padding style at the end

Please check if this is what you are looking for!!!

```js
$(".step").prepend('<span class="stepPos">1</span>')
```

```css
.stepPos{
 position:relative;
 left:-15px;
}


body{
  padding:20px
}

table{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:0px !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th >heading</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="step">value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table>
<tr>
  <th >heading2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="step">value2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This does nothing to remove the space in front of "value" and "value2" that the OP said he/she doesn't want.